# Pass comma separated variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable (pvlist) an array which contains data like so '`120123,345654`'. When I try passing only one value using `window.open` it works e.g when the array only has one value.
If I have more than one value in my array, I get a blank page with nothing. I have tried various solutions suggested which include:

```
window.open("../Functions/csv.php?refno="+pvlist);
window.open("../Functions/csv.php?refno="+pvlist+"");
window.open("../Functions/csv.php?refno="+pvlist.join(",")+"");
```

Any suggestion of what can be used to pass a variable with more than one comma separated value? all help appreciated.

**EDIT** 
variable pvlist is a variable with comma separated values

Comment: Does `pvlist` contain `['120123,345656']` or `[120123,345656]`?

Comment: It should be `csv.php` problem, not javascript one. And `+""` part is essentially a no-op.

Comment: Is the idea for `refno` to contain a single string with all of the values? Or do you want to handle it as an array in your PHP?

Comment: @SuneTrudslev pvlist contains data as 120123,345656. The items are being pushed into a variable of type []. var pvlist = [];

Comment: @raina77ow csv.php has no problem. Like I said if the pvlist contains only one value, it works. When it has more than one it doesn't

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, that is exactly what I am doing. I have a $_GET('refno') in my csv.php script.

Comment: And does your PHP correctly handle refno as a string with commas in it?

Comment: @nnnnnn now that you mention it. I am going through the PHP code as I suspect the server side code is the problem. Not the javascript. +1 upvote

Comment: @raina77ow You were right. csv.php had a problem. +1 upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the **join** method of array. That turns an array like this [1,2,3,4,5] into a string like this "1,2,3,4,5" (or whatever other separator you need)

Example:

```
window.open("../Functions/csv.php?refno=" + pvlist.join(','));
```

Comment: If `pvlist` is an array, then it does not have `.split` method. Only strings can be split.

Comment: Further to what Felix said, the method you are looking for is `.join()`.

Comment: Erm... may be I'm missing something, but why do you ignore the fact that Array.join(',') is essentially the same as Array.toString()? ) The OP's problem is not in JS, otherwise its first approach would work just fine.

Comment: I was not aware array.toString() is equivalent to array.join. Non the less, you should use .join() for readability if nothing else.

Comment: `"somestring" + pvlist` concatenates the result of `pvlist.toString()`  to the end of `"somestring"` where the `pvlist` elements will be joined with commas. So explicitly joining the array with `.join(',')` produces the same result though I agree it is more readable. But in any case OP already tried with `.join(",")` as shown in the question.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear. My variable has comma separated values inside it. Not an array. I'm suspecting the commas are being interpreted by window.open function as parameters

Comment: OK, then you shouldn't say you have an array, you have a string of comma separated values. Anyway to put this at the top of csv.php: var_dump($_GET['refno']). to see exactly what it receives. Or better give as the content of csv.php if you want help.

Comment: @DanF. and the rest, thanks guys. I read through the comments and rectified some code. At some point I was using encoding using base64 in php which must have caused an error since after removing it, it now works with many comma separated values in one variable. Actually all my suggestions in my question now work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using escape function for passing values. Then you can always decode later. Works fine. I had to pass comma separated values from JS file back to controller.

var fee = //comma separated value;
var data = escape(fee);

In java you can always decode this value using URLdecoder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).